# Managing user input's case in Python

Tags: python, case-sensitive

I have set up a script to say something when the user enters something other than `Yes`. However it still says this when the user says `Yes`. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Python 2.7.2.
Here is my code:

```
print 'Hi! Welcome!'
begin = raw_input ('Will you answer some questions for me? ')
if begin == 'yes':
    print 'Ok! Let\'s get started then!'
else:
    print 'Well then why did you open a script clearly entiled\'QUIZ\'?!'
```

Comment: You should use double quotes so you don't have to escape the quotation mark eg. `print "Ok! Let's get started then!"`

Comment: Hint: try `'yes' == 'Yes'` at the interpreter prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Just change the line

```
if begin == 'yes':
```

to

```
if begin.lower() == 'yes':
```

Because string compare is case sensitive, the match will only if true iff user enters the reply in lower case

Comment: @Lattyware: Do you see the difference in the posted time?

Comment: SO normally warns me when an answer has been posted as I am writing mine, so I presumed you would have seen that warning.

Comment: @Lattyware: Your first post was the first three lines. If you disagree now, its difficult to prove :-)

Comment: Ah, this is true - I do the whole post then edit in the links and formatting bit too much now to think about it. My apologies.

Comment: Guys, it's not "difficult to prove": If you're not sure who was first in the future, you can check the edit history by clicking on the modification time, e.g., `edited 2 hours ago`

Comment: @alexis Actually, it is. I edited mine within the grace period of 5 minutes (IIRC), so it doesn't get added as another edit.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Hadn't realized that.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is case sensitivity.

```
>>> "yes" == "Yes"
False
```

Try using [`str.lower()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) on the user input before your comparison to ignore case. E.g:

```
print 'Hi! Welcome!'
begin = raw_input ('Will you answer some questions for me? ')
if begin.lower() == 'yes':
    print 'Ok! Let\'s get started then!'
else:
    print "Well then why did you open a script clearly entiled\'QUIZ\'?!"
```

#If a single apostrophe is used inside the print str then it must be surrounded by double apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Abhijit's method also works if you just want to accept more than one version of a string from a user. For example, I'm using this to confirm whether the user wants to exit:

```
confirm = input('Are you sure you would like to exit? N to re-run program')
  if confirm.lower() in ('n','no'): #.lower just forces the users input to be changed to lower case
    print("I'll take that as a no.")
    return confirm #this then just goes back to main()
  else:
    exit()
```

This way either 'n' or 'N'; 'no' or 'NO' or 'nO' are all accepted cases of 'no'.